# Generate unique key in Java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptography

We are migrating a server project coded using NodeJs to one coded in Java. I'm not very into the cryptography thing but I need to "translate" the following instruction to Java.

```
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
```

Basically in the node js project they were using the js library crypto to generate a unique key, and I would need to do the same, no more, no less, in java. 
Anyone with crypto knowledge that can help here? What would be the equivalent in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, maybe SecureRandom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Random.nextBytes(byte[] bytes)
```

to populate a random byte array and then convert the bytes to hex using the strategies discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: `Random` doesn't provide cryptographically secure random bytes. `SecureRandom` should be used instead.

Comment: He isn't using it for cryptography. he just needs a random UUID.

Comment: The collisions with `Random` might be too high to call the result "unique". Anyway, [`UUID` also uses `SecureRandom` internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/UUID.java#UUID).

Comment: The implementation of nextBytes is doc'd here:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes(byte[])

so essentially it's calling nextInt() for each byte. I won't pretend to know enough about cryptography to know how much entropy this generates as opposed to other methods implemented by SecureRandom. That being said, I doubt there will be many collisions with this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use something like this

```
import java.util.uuid;
...

UUID  newUUID = UUID.randomUUID();

String.valueOf(newUUID);

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UUID from java:

```
UUID.randomUUID()
```

Through a quick search on google I got https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/05/how-generate-secure-random-numbers-in-various-programming-languages, have a look and for your case the closest thing will be:

```
SecureRandom csprng = new SecureRandom();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
csprng.nextBytes(randombytes);
```

This is in the blog.
Hope it helps.

Comment: `would need to do the same, no more, no less`

Comment: ok you want actually to pass the number of bytes and generate the key

Comment: Yes, this generates a unique key.  This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
new BigInteger(256, random).toString(32);
```